# Install ruby 2.0.0 rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

how to install ruby by using rvm i have error when i install ruby 2.0.0 and ruby 1.9.3:

**rvm install 2.0.0-p195**

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p195.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/sergey-chechaev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p195 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p195, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.0.0-p195 - #extracted to /Users/sergey-chechaev/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p195 (already extracted)
ruby-2.0.0-p195 - #configuring........
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/sergey-chechaev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /Users/sergey-chechaev/.rvm/log/1385379217_ruby-2.0.0-p195/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

**rvm install 1.9.3**

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p484.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/sergey-chechaev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p484 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p484, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p484 - #extracted to /Users/sergey-chechaev/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p484 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p484 - #configuring........
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/sergey-chechaev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p484 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /Users/sergey-chechaev/.rvm/log/1385379545_ruby-1.9.3-p484/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

i do not get what happen. I install `brew install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config apple-gcc42 libyaml readline libxml2 libxslt libksba openssl sqlite`and `xcode` too

Comment: Did you update to `Mavericks` recently?

Comment: yes i instal updates or no i not sure  )))

Comment: Try updating your development tools: `xcode-select --install`

Comment: what is in the log file `/Users/sergey-chechaev/.rvm/log/1385379217_ruby-2.0.0-p195/configure.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the latest Apple Xcode from the appstore. Open Xcode and install Command Line tools from the preferences. Try running rvm and installing ruby again.

Answer (score 3):

You can download only command line tools from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (need registration)
and install ruby from rvm.